# How to split bytes into a list of integers in Python-3?

Tags: python-3.x, split

What is the pythonic way of converting the following array of bytes into a list of integers in Python-3:

```
Input: b'34\n44\n-28\n-63\n22\n'

Desired output: [34, 44, -28, -63, 22]
```

Comment: `[int(x) for x in input.decode().split('\n')]`?

Comment: So you are just splitting on whitespace?

Comment: Alternatively `list(map(int, input.decode().split('\n')))`, but the list comprehension should be slightly faster and IMHO is more _pythonic_.

Comment: @pstatix: no need to decode. Everything works just the same if you drop the `.decode()` call.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In Python 3.6 I get a `TypeError` without the `decode()`. Full: _a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'_. Starting with a variable `temp = b'34\n44\n-28\n-63\n22\n'`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Solved, was trying to split on `'\n'`, the `str` representation, needed to split on `b'\n'`. Either way, result is the same!

Comment: @pstatix: yes, when you pass in an argument to `bytes.split()` it must be another bytes object or `None`. In this case, no argument is probably more flexible, or you could use `bytes.splitlines()`.

Comment: @pstatix: Exactly. I tried to split on '\n' too, got the following error: TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API. So I asked the question here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the same method as on a regular string. Split and map to `int()`:

```
[int(v) for v in bytesvalue.split()]
```

This works because `bytes` have many of the same methods (including [`bytes.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.split), and the [`int()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) accepts `bytes` values the same way it accepts `str` values:

> If *x* is not a number or if *base* is given, then *x* must be a string, `bytes`, or `bytearray` instance representing an integer literal in radix *base*.

Demo:

```
>>> bytesvalue = b'34\n44\n-28\n-63\n22\n'
>>> bytesvalue.split()
[b'34', b'44', b'-28', b'-63', b'22']
>>> [int(v) for v in bytesvalue.split()]
[34, 44, -28, -63, 22]
```